# Lua Require function on a full path name

Tags: path, lua, require

I need to call the require on a lua file that will not always be in the same place. I was trying to call require on the full path name but that doesn't seem to be working either. I even tried replacing one of my working normal requires with a correct full path name to the same file

example changing
    require "foo"
to 
    require "C:\Users\Me\MyLuaProject\foo"

but when i switched it to the full path name it could no longer find it. So I am wondering if you can even call require on a full path and if not how would i achieve the same result differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the directory containing the file to [package.path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path):

```
package.path = package.path .. ";C:\\Users\\Me\\MyLuaProject"
require "foo"
```

You can also add it to the LUA_PATH environment variable, but this is probably less easy to modify on the fly.

A common pattern for modules is to have abc.lua and abc/xyz.lua; to require files in a subdirectory like that, use the following:

```
require "abc"
require "abc.xyz"
```

Comment: i had to add a question mark as a wild case:
package.path = package.path .. ";/path/to/module/?.lua"
but maybe it's a linux thing

Answer (score 19):

If you just need to load a file, use `dofile`, which takes a path:

```
dofile("C:\\Users\\Me\\MyLuaProject\\foo")
```