# Can Lua's `require` handle paths containing hidden directories / full stops?

Tags: path, lua

Under Linux, using Lua 5.1, I have a lua script located under a hidden directory: `~/.texmf/lua/print_table.lua`. (It's LuaTeX-related, that's why it's in the texmf dir.) I ran `lua` interactively from my home directory, tried to `require` that file, and got the following error messages:

```
> require('.texmf/lua/print_table')
stdin:1: module '..texmf/lua/print_table' not found:
    no field package.preload['.texmf/lua/print_table']
    no file './/texmf/lua/print_table.lua'
    ... [file not found in other - irrelevant - trees, either, of course]

> require('/home/me/.texmf/lua/print_table')
stdin:1: module '/home/me/.texmf/lua/print_table' not found:
    no field package.preload['/home/me/.texmf/lua/print_table']
    no file './/home/me//texmf/lua/print_table.lua'
    ...
```

So, clearly `require` turns periods into slashes. Escaping the period did not work: I tried doubling the period, sticking a backslash in front of it, and sticking two backslashes in front of it. Is there any way to `require` a file that has a hidden directory (or any other full stop) in its path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require` needs a *module name*, not a *path*.

You may want to add `/home/me/.texmf/lua/?.lua` to `package.path` or `LUA_PATH`. Then you'll be able to say `require "print_table"`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `loadfile` instead of require; this way, you could specify direct path. There was a question about it recently...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868847/lua-require-function-on-a-full-path-name

Comment: Ah, I searched for "hidden directory" instead of "full path". So 'loadfile' accepts a path, while `require` only accepts a dot- or slash-separated module name and treats it in a somewhat pathy manner. All clear, now. Thanks, Bartek and lhf.